# Twitter Developer API: Card Validator

Tags: validation, twitter

https://etrak-plus.com:8443/default/flex/TwitterTest.jsp

I can not get https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator to validate the link above.  I keep getting "Server error. Please try again".

If you go to the link and view source it has the meta tags.

Also where is the Request Approval button for cards?
And how do you tweet Cards?

I cannot seem to find this information in the Twitter documentation.

EDITED

I removed the empty meta tags and tried again and still get "Server error. Please try again".